# How to link node project with postgresql?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I set up my app with https://github.com/javieraviles/node-typescript-koa-rest, after that add babel, objection, knex, pg. I want to start my project without errors.

I am getting this error

```
TypeORM connection error:  error: password authentication failed for user "user".
```

How can I set up  my project and manage users and databases?

Comment: Read Knex docs, https://knexjs.org/

Comment: Especially the [CLI](http://knexjs.org/#Migrations-CLI) and the [installation](http://knexjs.org/#Installation)